# Access a property of an imported class

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics

I have a subclass of UIView that displays some Core Graphics drawn in a CATiled Layer. I am doing the drawing in a seperate class and am rendering the drawing to the screen like this:

```
drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context {

CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
[self.myDrawing renderInContext:context];

}
```

in the myDrawing object I have several classes that I import to do the drawing. One of these classes has has a property of:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGPathRef path;
```

How do I access this property from my UIView? I tried

```
self.myDrawing.context.path
```

but it doesn't get me there. Any thoughts?

Comment: Without more of your code, I don't know if I can help you.

Comment: What do you mean by “it doesn't get me there”? What's the declaration of the `context` property in `self.myDrawing.context.path`? What class is the `path` property declared in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Peter! Your comment led me in the right direction.

What I was trying to do was to access the path property of an object inside of another object.
I did it with this:

```
self.myDrawing.myParser.path
```

Once I walked through my code I realized I was not asking an intelligible question.
Thanks for making me walk through my code word by word Peter!